# How did Ava Wilson lock herself in that shed in Supernatural?

Tags: supernatural

In the 21st episode of Season 2 of *Supernatural*, "All Hell Breaks Loose Part 1", Sam Winchester and all of the "psychic" children (including Ava, Jake, Lily, and, Andy) are all sent to an abandoned town as a *Hunger Games* style duel.

In the show Ava gets locked in a shed and is banging on the door crying for help. but the door is locked, and this seems normal until about halfway through the episode she ends up

> killing Andy

and trying to cover it up.

> As it turns out she has been there for about three months and has been killing all of the people being sent there.

But if that was true, then **how did she lock the door?** From the inside, with a padlock?

edit: I have realized that yeah you Ava could use her demons to lock herself in if it wasn't made of iron so usually something like this would be resolved but, If I remember correctly there was a great deal of rust on the lock allowing Sam to break the padlock, but the only metal that rusts is *Iron* (due to ferric oxide combining with oxygen)  so it couldn't have been her demons who put it there.

Comment: I am not entirely sure, as I watched it years ago, but I believe that some "psychic" children developed telekinetic abilities.

Comment: that is true, but assuming that not all of them have the same specialty how could she do it?

Comment: According to the [Supernatural wikia page](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Ava_Wilson) Ava could control Acheri deamons, so unless the lock was made of iron, she could have had a deamon lock her in.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple possibilities, but we don't get a canon explanation so this is mostly guesswork :

- Ava is later seen controlling a demon. She may have control one as well to lock her in the shed
- The chosen children develop powers over the years, thanks to their demon blood. They have only one power initially but, since they are meant to ultimately lead Azazel's army out of hell, they develope multiple powers.

Comment: while this is a very good answer if you remember she couldn't summon the demons until the line of salt was broken to kill andy, soooooo I doubt she would have had the power to make a demo  grab something made of iron and lock the door for her

Comment: What was made of iron ? It's been a long time since I watched that episode, but wasn't it a wooden shed ?

Comment: @Kalissar: But the lock was covered by rust, at least implying that it was iron.

Comment: metal can't rust unless it has iron in it